# lazy loading of express routes via firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

**EDITED**

Is there any way to load only the route that has been triggered via firebase?

Currently i have this code:

**index.ts**

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import App from "./api";

export const api = functions.https.onRequest(App);
```

**app.ts**

```
// usual configs helmet, service-accounts, load express passport, cors
const app = express();
registerApiRoutesTo(app);
```

**registerApiRoutesTo.ts**

```
import { Express } from "express";
import { config } from "firebase-functions";
import { readdirSync } from "fs";
import { resolve } from "path";

export default (app: Express) => {
  const apiVersion = `/${config().api.version}/`;
  const routeDirectory = resolve(__dirname, "..", "api", "routes");
  const directories = readdirSync(routeDirectory);

  directories.forEach(route => {
    const appRoute = require(`${routeDirectory}/${route}`);

    app.use(`${apiVersion + route}`, appRoute.default);
  });
};
```

and in my `api/routes` I have the following:

```
users
settings
accounts
..many more
```

Now this is working well, I also observe that when a user calls one of the api endpoint, the function will trigger and it will load all the routes again.

Is there any way make this **"manageable"** like `loading only the called routes`

ex:

If the user calls for the **user** route then `registerApiRoutesTo` would only load the **user** route

Comment: Could you edit the question to show some code that illustrates what doesn't work the way you'd like, and what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Give this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130700/organizing-routes-without-pre-loading-the-modules-in-nodejs-express) a read. It should provide some insights on what you are trying to do.

Comment: @JKleinne not exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Hello, could you then clarify what the end goal is? The whole reason of serverless computing and FaaS is to abstract low-level concepts such as this, namely it simplifies the scalability of applications while maintaining high availability.